# How can I see all instances of a class?

Tags: c#, uml

I have a short presentation at school for relations between classes (UML), and I want to show with code how composition and aggregation work in practical use and the difference between them. In order to do that however I want to be able to be able to see all active objects atm, to proove that the object I deleted and the object that was part of it are truly gone now.

This is a quick example of what I am trying to do:

```
List<Company>companies = new List<Company>(){ 
    new Company(){ 
      Name = "Greiner", 
      new Boss(){
        Name = "Hugo",
      },
   }, 
};

Company comp = companies.FirstOrDefault();
companies.Remove(comp);
```

Now I want to somehow show that the Boss is gone along with the company, not just the (indirect) reference to him. So I thought of looking at all active objects.

Is there any way to do this? I am aware that the garbage collector is supposed to do this, but I dont want to tell my fellow students to just believe my words.

Also I do tend to think overly complicated, so my approach might be completely backwards, so any suggestions how to proove the differences between aggregation and composition are welcome.

Regards

Andreas Postolache

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but I think your perspective is backwards.  Your class composition should represent the nature of the backing data (typically in a database).  It should not be brutally modified at runtime to reflect your data.  You'd be much better off modifying backing data and reflecting that data to a UI rather than modifying code structure.

Comment: What do you mean by "...show that..." when you talk about the garbage collector in the same paragraph?? WHAT do you want to show? How memory management works? And then: what has it got to do with UML??

Comment: I have a UML modell where Boss and Company have a composition relation, as in Boss is part of Company. And I also have the code implementation of that model. When I delete the Company object, the Boss object should get deleted too because of this relation. And I want to show that its truly gone, even from the memory. Look to Praveen Paulose's answer below, its basically answered, its just for some reason not working in my little test project yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a static counter within your classes to keep count of the no. of instances created. Increment this counter in the constructor and decrease it in the destructor. The class structure sample is shown below.

```
public class Company
{
    public static int counter = 0;
    public Company()
    {
        counter++;
    }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Boss Boss { get; set; }
        ~Company()
    {
        counter--;
    }
}

public class Boss
{
    public static int counter = 0;

    public Boss()
    {
        counter++;
    }

    public string Name {get;set;}

    ~Boss()
    {
        counter--;
    }
}
```

Now you can see the no. of instances by printing this counter wherever required.

You can now instantiate your class Company and check the count of objects.

```
Company company = new Company(){ Name = "Greiner",  Boss = new Boss(){ Name = "Hugo" }} ;

Console.WriteLine("Company: " + Company.counter.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Boss: " + Boss.counter.ToString());

company = null;
```

The output should result in Company: 1 and Boss: 1

Now on a Button Click write the following code

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Console.WriteLine("Company: " + Company.counter.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Boss: " + Boss.counter.ToString());
```

Note that you will have to call the garbage collection methods to force immediate collection or else you cannot guarantee when the object will be removed by the GC.

The output will now show 0 for both Company and Boss.

*Note: Use GC.Collect only in your classroom for demonstration purposes.*

Comment: Thank you this is a simple and quickly understandable way to do it, perfect for a short presentation. Problem is, my garbage collector does not seem to be doing his job. The Destructors never get called. I made sure to call the Garbacollector, but he still is not removing the objects.

Comment: Oh I definetly will, I was just wondering if you have any idea why my garbage collector is not actually deleting the objects. It should work in theory, but the GC just doesnt do it.

Comment: Call the GC outside of the method where you are setting the object to null. E.g. In your Form Load you write the class initialization and destruction. On a button click, add the code to GC.Collect and Wait for Pending Finalizers. If used within the same method, the GC holds the reference and does not mark it for deletion / cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection complicates things for you here - perhaps it would be more instructional to show this in native C++ instead. However, you can explicitly call GC.Collect() to force the garbage collection. To be able to track the deletion of the object, you can use the destructor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ExampleDeletion
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Company
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Boss CEO { get; set; }

            ~Company()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Company destroyed: " + Name);
            }
        }
        public class Boss
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }

            ~Boss()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Boss destroyed: " + Name);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();

            Add(ref companies);
            Remove(ref companies);

            GC.Collect();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static private void Add(ref List<Company> companies)
        {
            companies.Add(
                new Company()
                {
                    Name = "Greiner",
                    CEO = new Boss()
                    {
                        Name = "Hugo"
                    }
                });
        }

        static private void Remove(ref List<Company> companies)
        {
            Company comp = companies.FirstOrDefault();
            companies.Remove(comp);
        }
    }
}
```

One interesting thing I have noticed while trying this out is that if you remove the item from the list in the same scope where it was created, it does not get collected by GC. It looks like there is an implicit reference from the current scope which keeps the object alive. That was the reason why I pushed the creation of the item to a separate function.